# pick up objects inside a polygon, using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to collect all my items within a polygon, but I am encountering an error.

```
"reason": "failed to find geo_point field [SitePoint.coordinates]",
```

I spent some time trying to understand and I can't understand what's wrong

my index

```
{
  "took": 43,
  "timed_out": false,
  "hits": {
    "total": 5,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "xxxx",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "SitePoint": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              18.85491,
              -33.92305
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

my query

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_polygon" : {
                    "SitePoint.coordinates" : {
                        "points" : [
                            [18.85096,-33.96311],
                            [18.87787,-33.92564],
                            [18.85096,-33.96311]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What mapping do you get when running `GET my_index`?

Comment: `"SitePoint": {   "type": "geo_shape"  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you're using a `geo_polygon` query which operates on [`geo_point` fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html), whereas `SitePoint` seems to be a [`geo_shape`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html).

You need to use a [`geo_shape` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) instead of `geo_polygon`:

Try this query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_shape" : {
                    "SitePoint" : {
                        "shape": {
                           "type": "polygon",
                           "coordinates" : [
                               [18.85096,-33.96311],
                               [18.87787,-33.92564],
                               [18.85096,-33.96311]
                           ]
                        },
                        "relation": "within"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"reason": "invalid number of points [5] provided for geo_shape [envelope] when expecting an array of 2 coordinates"` In this case I can only use 2 coordinates, and I have 5, the first being the last as a polygon. I can't use it that way

Comment: Sorry, replace `envelope` by `polygon` and it should work